# Hugo Github Pages Error

Tags: github, themes, github-pages, hugo

I'm in the midst of starting a basic blog. I decided to try implementing github pages for the back end of my site using this particular theme (https://github.com/vickylai/hugo-theme-introduction).

I am able to successfully run both my site and my theme locally. However if I go to my pages link (https://ericksnetwork.github.io/) I get this 404 error:

```
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.
```

I followed everything on the Hugo guidelines along with the guidelines on the actual github theme readme. Any advice would be appreciated.

This is the folder structure of what currently works locally:

```
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\.gitignore
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\.travis.yml
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\archetypes
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\archetypes\blog.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\archetypes\default.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\archetypes\projects.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\CHANGELOG.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\config.toml
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\about.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\blog
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\blog\coffee-ipsum.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\blog\hipster-ipsum.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\blog\startup-ipsum.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\contact.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\projects
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\projects\Design.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\projects\Photography.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\content\projects\Writing.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img\camera.jpg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img\fav.ico
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img\plant.jpg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img\profile.jpg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\exampleSite\static\img\workday.jpg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\images
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\images\screenshot.png
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\images\tn.png
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\_default
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\_default\list.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\_default\single.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\_default\taxonomy.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\_default\terms.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\404.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\blog
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\blog\list.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\blog\single.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\index.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\blogsection.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\footer.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\header.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\li.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\nav-list.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\nav-single.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\projects.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\partials\social.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\projects
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\layouts\projects\list.html
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\LICENSE
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\README.md
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\sass
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\sass\dark-style.sass
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\sass\light-style.sass
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\css
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\css\dark-style.css
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\css\font-awesome.min.css
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\css\light-style.css
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\css\nunito_sans.css
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.svg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.woff
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.woff2
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\FontAwesome.otf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-Black.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-BlackItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-Bold.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-BoldItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-ExtraLight.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-Italic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-Light.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-LightItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-Regular.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\NunitoSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\fonts\OFL.txt
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\img
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\img\favicon.ico
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\img\workday.jpg
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\js
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\js\jquery-3.3.1.min.js
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\js\moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\js\moment-timezone.js
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\static\js\moment.js
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\textfile.txt
C:\Users\erick\Documents\Projects\ericksnetwork.github.io\themes\introduction\theme.toml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this in the future - I was simply missing the "hugo" command which publishes your site into a Public folder. This you then drop into your 'pages' repository.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit your github link http://USERNAME.github.io and it is working fine now for you.

[image: It is working for you]

Enjoy !!! github services.

Comment: Ah that link was just a placeholder. My github link is here: https://ericksnetwork.github.io/. Still does not work. :(

Comment: On your github account , click setting menu at the top right page and check the the link at which your site is published.

Comment: Did you cloned from https://github.com/vickylai/hugo-theme-introduction

Answer (score 0):

In case you have cloned from 
https://github.com/vickylai/hugo-theme-introduction

then you first need to set-url for your own account.

Cross check :

Step 1. in gitbash type the command : git remote -v and look for the address where the changes will be pushed from git.

Step 2: Set the new url to your repository address :

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/YourUserName/NameofYourRepo

Step 3: remote -v . Now the adress to push your changes will have changed and you can push easily by .

Step 4 : git push origin master

Hope that resolves your issue.[image: remote address issue]